# How do I know the configured username (administrator and operator) in HP procurve?

Tags: hp-procurve

I truly appreciate your help on this last occasion.

I would use HP procurve switch now . (e.g. pc5510 pc2910 pc2510)

I would like to know user account set in HP procurve switch .
But I could not find out commands to display user account set 
in HP procurve switch.

I would run "show running-config" command .
But user account name is not described in running-config .

How do I know the configured user account name in HP procurve switch ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Provision switches support the *manager* and *operator* users only.

You can set a local user name (`password manager user-name <username>`) but I don't think you can look those up. However, `show running-config` displays `password manager` if this is set up.